# Allow 1 access at a time using fopen()

Tags: php

I'd like to allow 1 access at a time to a `.txt` file until the script finishes, so that it shows the message "Busy" when I open the same PHP again.

I have tried this:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('file.txt', 'w+');
if (flock($file, LOCK_EX)) {sleep(60); flock($file, LOCK_UN);}
else {echo 'Busy';}
fclose($file);
```

However it never shows the "Busy" message. Every new tab I open is in "sleep" mode. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for flock](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php) is extremely poor.

As stated in the top comment:

> If the file has been locked with LOCK_EX in another process, the CALL WILL BLOCK UNTIL ALL OTHER LOCKS have been released.

The result of this is, you will always be blocking on the call to `flock`. Your `else` clause would only execute if there is some error that prevents the file lock from being created - *not* when the file is already locked.